# mongo db to sql conversion 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mongodb

```
db.music.find({deleted: {$ne: true}});
```

the above code is in mongo db

I want to know how to write the equivalent for this in sql

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from music where deleted != true;
```

or, optimized:

```
select * from music where deleted == false;
```

Depending on the version of SQL, the `false` could be `'false'`, `0` or `'0'`

Assuming:

- You're already on the right database (no need to put `use my.db` at the beginning of your script)
- Your `deleted` column is of type boolean or bit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your storing `[deleted]` as a bit or nullable bit then :

```
Select * from [music] where [deleted] != 1
```

But you can't use sql to query MongoDB, you know that right?